# getBoundingClientRect не коректная работа с zoom

Tags: javascript, css

```
<div style="transform: scale(2)">
  <img style="transform: translate(24.375px, 76.375px) scale(1)"></img>
<div>
```

Когда я прошу `getBoundingClientRect` у `img` то `left right top bottom` возвращаются некорректные данные то есть при движении картинки в право `left right` уменьшаются (тоже и с `top bottom`). Хотя если убрать с `div` `transform` то все работает корректно.

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста рабочий пример

Comment: эта проблем описана в доках.  getBoundingClientRect  выводит данные без учета  transform.   для получения сначений с учетом зума нужно или  умножать на коефициенты или не пользоваться getBoundingClientRect .  https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=77998 https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1066435 . не помню где но в стандартах описано поведение transform  - и все браузеры короче  не учитывают аго в getBoundingClientRect

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понимаю, вы делаете `zoom` для картинки. Может вам подойдет такой вариант

```js
function zoom(image) {
  image.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    var x = (e.offsetX / this.offsetWidth) * 100;
    var y = (e.offsetY / this.offsetHeight) * 100;
    this.style.backgroundPosition = x + '% ' + y + '%';
  });
}

zoom(document.querySelector('figure'));
```

```css
div {
  width: 250px;
}

figure {
  background-image: url(http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/img/homepage/golf-1-top-82328.jpg);
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

img {
  transition: opacity .5s;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}

img:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/img/homepage/golf-1-top-82328.jpg" />
  </figure>
</div>
```